Name of a SciFi/dystopian movie involving nasal or mouth implanted tracker/explosive
I remember seeing this movie in the 90s when I was a kid. There isn't much detail that I can remember but what I do remember is that it was a future dystopian world.
In which I think there was some kind of concentration camp or prison system/colony or quarantine. Everyone had some kind of tracker that would explode if they went out of bounds or acted out of line (or perhaps turrets would trigger the explosive or shoot them down which lead me to the mistake of thinking it was Running Man but it wasn't).
What stands out the most in my memory is how they implanted the device. Upon processing, they would stick the person's head in this automated machine that would lock the head in place so they couldn't move and the mechanical device would shove the explosive/tracker into their nose (or mouth, I can't remember specifically).
I also thought it was Total Recall, but it didn't show the device being inserted in the manner I remember. This movie has been bugging me for months and I'd like a trip down memory lane and watch it again. Thanks a million in advance.

Total Recall had the reverse. The device was forcibly removed through the nose :D
